# Is this possible to disable Esc key, click and enable hover in Flutter web iframe?

Tags: flutter, iframe

I am displaying a iframe/url into my flutter web app. In this iframe I want to enable only hover and disable escape key and click event. Is this possible to do?

Following  is complete code to display iframe

```
// ignore: avoid_web_libraries_in_flutter
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'dart:js' as js;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class IframeExp extends StatefulWidget {
  final String url;

  const IframeExp({super.key, required this.url});
  @override
  State<IframeExp> createState() => _IframeExpState();
}

class _IframeExpState extends State<IframeExp> {
  final IFrameElement _iFrameElement = IFrameElement();

  @override
  void initState() {
    _iFrameElement.style.height = '100%';
    _iFrameElement.style.width = '100%';
    _iFrameElement.src = widget.url;
    _iFrameElement.style.border = 'none';

// ignore: undefined_prefixed_name
    ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
      'iframeElement',
      (int viewId) => _iFrameElement,
    );

    _iFrameElement.onKeyPress.listen((event) {
      print("[Escape]${event.charCode} ${String.fromCharCode(event.charCode)}");
    });
    _iFrameElement.onClick.listen((event) {
      print("[Escape] ${event}");
    });

    window.onKeyPress.listen((KeyboardEvent e) {
      print("[Escape] ${e.charCode} ${String.fromCharCode(e.charCode)}");
    });

    super.initState();
  }

  final Widget _iframeWidget = HtmlElementView(
    viewType: 'iframeElement',
    key: UniqueKey(),
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: _iframeWidget,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void disableEscapeKey() {}

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
}
```

In this iframe, I want to achieve the following behaviors:

```
Enable only hover events.
Disable the escape key.
Disable click events.
```

I have tried using onKeyPress and onClick events on the IFrameElement, but it doesn't seem to prevent the escape key or click events. Additionally, I have attached a general window.onKeyPress event listener, but it doesn't capture events within the iframe.

Is there a way to achieve these specific event handling requirements within an iframe in Flutter web?

Answer (score 0):

yes
it possible
you can change whenever and whatever

Comment: Can you please help me to do that

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.
You can use "RawKeyboardListerner" widget to capture keyboard events and adjust the iframe's properties accordingly

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).